# Passing a static array to a function

Tags: programming, c++

I have a functon that creates a instance of `KeyReport` and I want to fill statically the `KeyReport.keys` array. I'm new in the Arduino world so I'll put a example to explain it better:

```
void sendKey(byte keys[6], byte modifiers)
{
  KeyReport report = {0};

  report.keys = keys; // This is my main trouble
  report.modifiers = modifiers;
  report.reserved = 1;
  Keyboard.sendReport(&report);
}

void setup(){
delay(3000);
sendKey( {0x17,0,0,0,0,0}, 0x5); // I want to send hardcoded reports like this
}

void loop(){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
report.keys = keys; // This is my main trouble
```

You can't assign the contents of one array to the contents of another array.  You can only copy the contents manually from one to the other.

The simplest way is with a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    report.keys[i] = keys[i];
}
```

There is a helper function - `memcpy()` - which can do it for you if you prefer:

```
memcpy(report.keys, keys, 6);
```

It effectively does exactly the same thing - copy 6 bytes starting from the address of `keys` into the addresses starting at `report.keys`.

As for the "hard coded" reports I suggest you create some `const` arrays in the global context - and even use `PROGMEM` to ensure they consume no RAM. That, of course, requires an entirely different way of passing and accessing the data.  It may be simpler to split the report into 6 individual variables and pass each byte separately:

```
void sendKey(byte k0, byte k1, byte k2, byte k3,
             byte k4, byte k5, byte modifiers)
{
  KeyReport report = {0};

  report.keys[0] = k0;
  report.keys[1] = k1;
  report.keys[2] = k2;
  report.keys[3] = k3;
  report.keys[4] = k4;
  report.keys[5] = k5;
  report.modifiers = modifiers;
  report.reserved = 1;
  Keyboard.sendReport(&report);
}

sendKey(0x17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x05);
```

Yes, it's a little more long winded in the function, but calling the function is somewhat more simplified over the other options.

Comment: +35: Really good answer. Your last method is the best for me.

Comment: One last question: Is ok to use a `for` loop to clear the `report.keys` array?

Comment: Yep, perfectly fine. `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { report.keys[i] = 0; }`